# How to keep separate materials of merged Geometry

Tags: three.js, geometry, buffer-geometry

I managed to merge 2 pieces of geometry, namely plane and text. But the two materials must be separated at the end. How to do this ?

```
 const globalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pin_png/img_gps_dasloop_online.png"
);
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
const workerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(`Id : ${dbId}`, {
  font: "monaco",
  size: 1,
  height: 0,
  curveSegments: 3,
});
textGeometry.computeBoundingBox();

const workerIdMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, globalMaterial);
const workerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, workerMaterial);

// Merging
modelGeometry.merge(workerMesh.geometry, workerMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.merge(workerIdMesh.geometry, workerIdMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
const workerBufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(
  modelGeometry
);
this.humanModel = new THREE.Mesh(workerBufferGeometry, workerMaterial);
```

Comment: Usually if you're merging multiple geometries, they'll be sharing the same material. Why are you merging the geometries if you want to use two separate materials? It seems counter-productive to merge them in this case, since the renderer would be doing two separate render calls anyway.

Comment: The reason is because I want to make them one call. For example I can move them in one set position. Any suggestion ?